# CSS adjust brightness of image background and not content

Tags: html, css, filter

The section has a background image with content on top.
I want to decrease the brightness of only the background image in the section and not the content.

I have tried the below, however, the brightness still applies to all and not just the image.

```
<!-- Section -->
<div id="section1">
    <div id="content">



    <h1 class="heading">headline text</h1>
    <h4 class="subHeading"> Sub-headline text</h4>

    <!-- Call to action button -->
    <br><br>
    <button> Join our wait list </button>

</div>
```

```
#section1 {
background: url('../images/headerimage1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);
filter: brightness(0.5);
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
filter: brightness(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new element of transparent black that overlays just the background, with the contents of your div sitting in front of it.

```
<div id="section1">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#section1 {
    background: url('../images/headerimage1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
}

#section1::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the brightness does not seem to apply to the background

Comment: sorry I made a mistake when I first wrote, I've since edited it and added in the `position: absolute`

Comment: one quick suggestion. How would i be able to center the content. text-align:center or margin: 0 auto; doesnt seem to work

Comment: you will probably need to make sure your content div has the same width as the parent, since it is positioned absolutely now. `width: 100%` should work