# beginner css => apply property to only one element

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, frontend

so I have this code:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

html { 
background: url(bg_image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<img src="logo.png">

</body>

</html>
```

> How can I add brightness to my background image, without impacting logo.png ?

***EDIT: I tried adding the line "filter: brightness(0.5);" to the css, but the logo and everything else is impacted since this property applies to the whole HTML code. How can I overcome this problem?***

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "add brightness"? What have you tried?

Comment: @MichaelCoker question edited .

Comment: you tried adding the filter to what? which element? - please add a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS adjust brightness of image background and not content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066085/css-adjust-brightness-of-image-background-and-not-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the background in it's own unique element and use a negative `z-index` to put it behind the rest of the content.

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}
.bg {
  background: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional library to make your work easy;a library like material Ui gives you something called paper, it acts as a wrapper and therefor you can change property and attribute of it easily.

As in the above said changing z-index: -1 is a good point to start.